# Unable to install MongoD

Tags: database, mongodb

I have been trying to install MongoD by using "./mongod" command in the terminal. The cd is 'bin'. Apple is unable to open this file because it cannot open this file. What should I do?
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzJ6z.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVWnX.jpg)

The software that I am using is macOS 14.3.1

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: No error message? A very common problem is, that the default dbPath `/data/db` does not exist or lacks permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to `System Preferences> Security & Privacy > Allow apps downloaded from`:

Allow the same and you will be able to install.